# android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton implenetation of FAB reduces image size

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

So I have started migrating to the official support design library for an Android app of mine, replacing elements as I go. I just replaced an `FAB` (implemented as `ImageButton`) with official `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`. But the icon inside the button is smaller as compared to the one it was in `ImageButton`. What may have been a reason?

`FloatingActionButton`'s implementation:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />
```

Tried adding `app:fabSize="normal` but that didn't work, either.

This is how it looks after using `FloatingActionButton`:

[image]

And this is how it looked like while using it as a `ImageButton`:

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Set scale type to `android:scaleType="center"`

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess since you haven't provided any details at all. The design library's `FloatingActionButton` has padding calculations which will shrink the icon if it is too large, whereas your `ImageButton` probably just centers the icon with no scaling at all. I'm guessing that you would not observe this behavior if you were using a correctly sized 24dp icon, like the ones you get from: https://www.google.com/design/icons/.

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'correctly sized' bit? There are other size options on the website as well.

Comment: Following the [official design guildlines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button), a FAB icon should be 24dp, meaning that it should be [24x24 px at mdpi](http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/#screen-densities-and-icon-dimensions).

Comment: And does this rule apply for icons other than FAB? Like toolbar, action bar, and navigation bar icons?

Comment: There are difference rules for different areas. You can refer to the linked cheatsheet or look it up yourself.

Comment: I just checked. I was using the 24dp density image. I downloaded the 36dp one and replaced it and now it is working fine. 
Though, this is rather a patch than a fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use : `app:maxImageSize="..dp"` to change the size of your icon!